# Postgres pgcrypto privliledges

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto

I intsalled the pgcrypto extension as the superuser like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```

As the superuser, I tested it, and it works find:

```
select gen_salt('bf');
           gen_salt
-------------------------------
 $2a$06$CJPcLcOBZnCEl.Z5ChrSbO
```

But, when logging in as a different user, I get an error as follows:

```
select gen_salt('bf');
ERROR:  function gen_salt(unknown) does not exist
```

How do I make the pgcrypto library visible to all users?

Thanks.

Comment: You're sure you logged in to the same database? Extensions are per database.

Comment: lol. Silly mistake. That was the problem. Add that as an answer if you would, and, I can mark it correctly for others.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PostgreSQL extensions are per database. If you log in to another database, the extension is not available there. By default the functions are usable by any user.

Comment: For those who are wondering of how to enable extensions, in the left pane of pgAdmin, expand the _Databases_ rollout -> right click on extensions -> select _Create_ -> select _Extension_ -> in the _Name_ field, select your preferred extension name (e.g. `pgcrypto`) -> click _Save_.